# Proving $L^2$ boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have tried to solve this problem several times, and I still cannot find a good answer. Maybe I'm too naive, and the problem is really complicated.

Consider a nonnegative function $g$ defined on $(0,\infty)$. Assume additionally that 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{g(s)}{\sqrt{s}}ds <\infty.
$$
Consider now the operator for $x>0$,
$$
Tf(x) := \int_0^\infty g(xs)f(s)ds.
$$
The question now is simple: show that $Tf$ is in $L^2$ provided $f$ is also in $L^2$. Could you help me with ideas to prove this result? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   &\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}g(xs)f(s)ds\right|^2dx \\
   & = \mbox{( let s=u/x ) }\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}g(u)f(u/x)\frac{du}{x}\right|^2dx \\
  & = \int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{g(u)^{1/2}}{u^{1/4}} \frac{u^{1/4}g(u)^{1/2}f(u/x)}{x}du\right|^2dx \\
  & \le \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{g(u)}{\sqrt{u}}du\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}g(u)f(u/x)^2}{x^2}du\,dx \\
  & = C\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}g(u)f(u/x)^2}{x^2}dudx,
  \;\;\; C=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{g(u)}{\sqrt{u}}du \\
  & = C\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{u}g(u)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(u/x)^2}{x^2}dxdu \\
  & = \mbox{ ( v=u/x ) } C\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{u}g(u)\frac{1}{u}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(v)^2 dv du \\
  & = C^2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(v)^2dv
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
     \left\|\int_{0}^{\infty}g(xs)f(s)ds\right\|_{L^2} \le C\|f\|_{L^2},
  \;\;\; C=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{g(u)}{\sqrt{u}}du.
$$

Comment: Very tricky but beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: @Arigato : Thank you. I was surprised how well this worked out. If you select the checkmark next to my answer, that accepts this solution. You can also up-choose it with the arrow, which you may have already done.